# PDFBOX filling document from my html fields

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I've got a problem with PDFBOX.

So i created a simple code:

```
public class DelegationsPdf{
public Delegations getPDF(Delegations delegations) throws IOException{

    PDDocument delegation = new PDDocument();
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = delegation.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();

    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    delegation.addPage(page);
    page = delegation.getPage(0);

    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(delegation, page);
    content.beginText();
        content.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 20);
        content.setLeading(14.5f);
        content.newLineAtOffset(275, 750); 
        content.showText("Delegations");
    content.endText();

    content.beginText();
        content.newLineAtOffset(50 ,650);
        content.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
        content.showText("Worker:");
    content.endText();

    // FILL THE FIELD
    content.beginText();
        PDField name = pdAcroForm.getField(delegations.getName());
        content.newLineAtOffset(100 ,650);
        content.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
          pdAcroForm.getFields().add(name);
    content.endText();

    content.close();
    delegation.save("C:/delegation.pdf");
    delegation.close();
    return delegations;
}
```

So please tell my why the code under comment field "/fill the field" doesnt work properly? It gets information about name from my delegations class. Can you help me? When i run this and click button, I've got error with NULL.

Comment: Of course it is null. `pdAcroForm.getField(delegations.getName());` won't return anything because your document doesn't have any field. Btw your code is confusing. A PDDocument object should be named "document" or "delegationDocument" but not "delegation". A PDField should be called "field" and not "name".

Comment: I suggest you look at https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/ , this shows how to create a form.

Comment: Oh yes, I've figured out that I have to add Fields. Names was changed by me, cause I wanted just to know what is wrong.

So.. Firstly, when I created a template i need to create forms and add it there (from examples on apache svn - FillFormField?). But how can I add position of each field?

Comment: _I've figured out that I have to add Fields_ Please include all the relevant code in the question. The position of the field is the rectangle, see the CreateSimpleForm.java example.

Comment: Umm, I just dont know PDFBox really well yet.. and that was whole code which i wrote. But that was quite stupid, when i didnt add fields. 

I try it and will add comment if needed

Comment: Yes I've got this but - can you explain me why I've got 2.0.7 PDFBox version and got error like this:


"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"U+0105 ('aogonek') is not available in this font Times-Roman encoding: WinAnsiEncoding"

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#fontencoding . And current version is 2.0.8.

Comment: The section at that link probably should be extended to explain which glyphs are present for standard 14 fonts.

Comment: @mkl but that is mentioned in Appendix D, page 653.

Comment: @Tilman but the section seems to indicate that people can find out with charmap.exe on Windows which is not appropriate for standard 14 fonts. Thus, the section should make clear that the "If not, but if it is available in" part is not applicable for standard 14 fonts.

Comment: @mkl sorry, I still don't get it - it means to say that if the disk font has the glyph, then it can be loaded with `PDType0Font.load()`. If you still think it is ambigous, maybe enter old and new text in PDFBOX-3330.

Comment: Thanks guys, I used just PDType0Font.load() and now works with my national words.

Comment: @KonradP please delete your question or answer it yourself, to avoid orphans.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr can you tell me another thing about pdfbox? As in my example above I've got for every new line with text, a long code (beginText(), lineAtOffset(), showText and endText() ). 

How can I do that faster/easier? I tried just one begin and endText, but content.newLine() has too low space between.

Comment: You can set / change that space with `setLeading()`.

Comment: Great! And maybe about styling our pdf file (tables/colours/header with logo) - have we got something?

Answer (score 1):

So, finally, problem solved with your help.

Firstly, I had to know that when I "download" my value which I want to fill from HTML form, I need to create a field (form) in pdfbox and fill it then.

Secondly, I need to use PDType0Font.load() for special characters (UTF 8).

Thanks